# MiKTeX: [...] does not seem to be a local package repository

Tags: errors, packages, installing, miktex

I used MiKTeX 2.9 on windows.
I have downloaded a package I want to install from the internet (manually, not through MiKTeX). The archive (`*.lmza`) containing the package was saved to a directory on my `C:\` drive.
Through MikTeX -> Maintenance -> Settings -> Packages -> Change...
I can select the directory in which I have saved the archive containing the package.
However, if I choose `Packages shall be installed from a directory` and choose the location of the package, I get this error message:
`C:\my\package\is\here does not seem to be a local package repository.`
What does it take for a directory/folder to become a `local package repository`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to any package archive you store in any directory, at least these three other files need to be present:

```
miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma
```

These three contain the complete package list. Once those archives are present, the directory/folder can be specified as `local package repository`

---

These CURRENT archives can be found at [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages?lang=en).
**Use this Link above and in browser search for miktex-zz**

Comment: And where did you find these files?

Comment: @Kore-N see my edit

Comment: I also had to add `miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma` - from ctan.
I don't know why it didn't get downloaded with the option `--package-set=complete download`....?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Though I used MiKTeX **Net Installer** to download all the packages but still following file was missing:

miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma

and I got the same error message, as posted in the question then I downloaded the missing file from following Website.
http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/packages/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

Now I can install a package from the local repository.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The approved location of that file is in the accepted answer your location is a specific mirror and may not always be available