# Having trouble with MikTex and fonts for custom package, missing file

Tags: fonts, miktex

I'm trying to get a custom document class working on a Windows PC where I do not have administrative rights. MikTex can't access its package repository, and so far I've been forced to install a large amount of packages by hand which is really time consuming.

Now, when I try to compile my document, I run into this bug:

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "main.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\x\Downloads\rtthesisex-exjobb\rtthesisex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\x\Downloads\rtthesisex-exjobb\rtthesisex\main.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
----- SNIP (loading packages) -----
Option `squaren' provided!
)) (C:\Users\x\Downloads\rtthesisex-exjobb\rtthesisex\main.aux)
(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\omljkpw.fd)
(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\omsjkpw.fd)
(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\omxjkp.fd)
(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\ujkpexa.fd)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd")
(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\t1jkpk.fd)
======================================================================
miktex-maketfm.exe: Try Again
miktex-maketfm.exe: Data: get host by name failed in tcp_connect()
======================================================================
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The jkpmn8t source file could not be found.

Running hbf2gf.exe...


hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0)



Couldn't find `jkpmn.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font jkpmn8t.

! Font T1/jkpk/m/n/10=jkpmn8t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.17 \begin{document}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

I have no idea how to fix this manually. I have tried reinstalling the package, but there are no .cfg files included in kpfonts. Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: See also [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install everything by hand. Create a local repository. You need the two miktex-zz...-files and the miktex packages you want to install. Put everything in some folder and then use this folder. For details see e.g.
[MiKTeX: [...] does not seem to be a local package repository](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111612/miktex-does-not-seem-to-be-a-local-package-repository).

Ignore the message about a `.cfg` file. maketfm is looking for it as a last resort. The real problem is the missing `.tfm` file. You probably put it in the wrong place. All the `.fd` files are in the wrong folder too: They belong in `tex\latex\kpfonts`.