# KOMA-Script Installation fails

Tags: packages, miktex, koma-script, installing

Because I am using a Proxy in our company using the auto install of the MiKTeX Package Manager does not work for me. Instead I tried installing it manual by downloading the `pgf.tar.lzma` from a mirror.

When I try to add the package I get the following error message:

```
package="koma-script", arhiveFile="C:\Users\user\Documents\latex-packages\koma-script.tar.lzma", expectedMD5="8540ac6593530e7b58d865a2f227ea5e", actualMD5="5faf6bfa841513bcfbd4a968ca52a495"
```

Is there a way to bypass the checksum mechanism?

Comment: unless I misunderstood the question, if the checksum is wrong it will be the wrong file (or a truncated file), so bypassing the check won't help

Comment: if auto-install doesn't work you could use texlive rather than miktex which doesn't try to download packages on the fly in the same way.

Comment: It is not enough to download only the pgf.tar.lzma, you also need the suitable miktex databases (the two files starting with miktex-zz). Put them in the same folder (some folder outside miktex) as the pgf-lzma and then use this folder as local repository.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have them already - otherwise it would not work at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I dont want to install another packet manager. Also I have downloaded the package from a CTAN mirror so it should work...+

Comment: But do you have the **suitable** versions? Did you download them at the same time from the same repository as the package you are trying to install?

Comment: No different times, but the pgf is recent

Comment: Well then it is quite possible that the md-sums differ.

Comment: I don't think, that `pgf.tar.lzma` will be the KOMA-Script package.

Comment: yes apparently there was an update on the miktex packages - thanks guys

Comment: BTW: Manual KOMA-Script installation could alternatively be done using the [installation package from the KOMA-Script repositoy](https://komascript.de/node/2051).

Answer (score 2):

If you [create a local repository for MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111612/miktex-does-not-seem-to-be-a-local-package-repository) you always should download all files from the same server/mirror. Otherwise it could happen, that the version information at the package management files `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma` and `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma` do not correspond with the packages you've downloaded.

So for installation of KOMA-Script from a local repository you have to download at least `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma`, `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma` and `koma-script.tar.lzma` from the same server, copy it to one (new) directory and do the installation from that local directory. Note, if you are using the generic download URL `http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/…` for the download, the mirror can be different for each file. So please use a dedicated server address from the [CTAN mirrors list](https://ctan.org/mirrors/).